# AdaDelta optimization algorithm using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I was studying the AdaDelta optimization algorithm so I tried to implement it in Python, but there is something wrong with my code, since I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

I did not find something about what is causing that error. According to the message, it's because of this line of code:

`rms_grad = np.sqrt(self.e_grad + epsilon)`

This line is similar to this equation:

`RMS[g]t=√E[g^2]t+ϵ`

> I got the core equations of the algorithm in this article: http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#adadelta

Just one more detail: I'm initializing the `E[g^2]t` matrix like this:

`self.e_grad = (1 - mu)*np.square(nabla)`

Where nabla is the gradient. Similar to this equation:

`E[g2]t = γE[g2]t−1 + (1−γ)g2t`
(the first term is equal to zero in the first iteration, just like the line of code above)

So I want to know if I'm initializing the E matrix the wrong way or I'm doing the square root inappropriately. I tried to use the `pow()` function but it doesn't work. If anyone could help me with this I would be very grateful, I'm trying this for weeks.

> Additional details requested by andersource:

Here is the entire source code on github: https://github.com/pedrovbeltran/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/experimental/modified-networks/network2_with_adadelta.py .

Comment: Could you please include some more code as context? The class definition / method body?

Comment: Thank you for the reply andersource! I'll edit the post including some additional details, okay? :)

Comment: Thanks! The error seems quite strange, could please also add the following `print`s and include them in the question:
 `print(type(np))`; 
 `print(type(self.e_grad_w))`; 
 `print(type(self.e_grad_w + epsilon))`

Comment: I added today the entire source code on my GitHub. If you need any more information, please ask. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: <class 'module'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>        Are the outputs of your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `self.e_grad_w` is an `ndarray` of shape `(2,)` which further contains two additional `ndarray`s with 2d shapes, instead of directly containing data. This seems to be initialized in `e_grad_initializer`, in which `nabla_w` has the same structure. I didn't track where this comes from all the way back, but I believe once you fix this issue the problem will be resolved.

Comment: Hello! I take some time to comment over your solution because I was working hard to make this work and I did major modifications in the code and correct some issues. I solve my problem iterating the list, because, as you said, `self.e_grad_w` is a list with two arrays in. I'm a beginner in this world of ANNs, so it took me some time for me to process all this information. Now that I solve this issue, the problem now is the accuracy of the network because it's worse than other algorithms, which is pretty strange. I'll re-post my code on GitHub for you to take a look. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Now you can see my code right here with the full implementation: https://github.com/pedrovbeltran/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/tree/experimental/modified-networks/adadelta I hope that is more organized than the previous one, now that I am getting the way GitHub works.

Comment: Glad to help :) Regarding the accuracy, if you have an issue with it I suggest posting a different question specifically for that to encourage more people to try to help